# How can I return an array of object based on matching ids?

Tags: json, lodash

I am trying to match the ids of two json files and return the matching objects. These are the 2 json files:

```
{
  "een": {
    "id": "100",
    "title": "Entertainment and stuff"
  },
  "twee": {
    "id": "107",
    "title": "Sport for everyone"
  },
  "drie": {
    "id": "108",
    "title": "Eating is good"
  }
}
```

This is the second one:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Entertainment",
    "id": "100",
    "price": 2600,
    "gifted": false
  },
  {
    "name": "Sport",
    "id": "107",
    "price": 2500,
    "gifted": false
  }
]
```

As a result of the 2 matching idvalues I should get:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Entertainment",
    "id": "100",
    "price": 2600,
    "gifted": false,
    "title": "Entertainment and stuff"
  },
  {
    "name": "Sport",
    "id": "107",
    "price": 2500,
    "gifted": false,
    "title": "Sport for everyone"
  }
]
```

I was wondering if there was a fancy way using lodash or something else and do this in a nice compact way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution would be to use [**merge**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#merge) to merge two objects that have the `id` as the key. This can be done using [**keyBy**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#keyBy) on the array and also on the values of the first object. [**Intersection**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#intersection) is used find ids that are in both arrays.

```
let list1 = {
  "een": {
    "id": "100",
    "title": "Entertainment and stuff"
  },
  "twee": {
    "id": "107",
    "title": "Sport for everyone"
  },
  "drie": {
    "id": "108",
    "title": "Eating is good"
  }
}

let list2 = [
  {
    "name": "Entertainment",
    "id": "100",
    "price": 2600,
    "gifted": false
  },
  {
    "name": "Sport",
    "id": "107",
    "price": 2500,
    "gifted": false
  }
]

let o1 = _.keyBy(_.values(list1), 'id');
let o2 = _.keyBy(list2, 'id');

let matchingIds = _.intersection(_.keys(o1), _.keys(o2));

let result = _.chain(o1)
    .pick(matchingIds)
    .merge(_.pick(o2,matchingIds))
    .values()
    .value()
```

Comment: You're missing the last step.  I think OP wants to merge only those objects whose ids match.  So your result should somehow omit the object with an id of 108.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @GruffBunny's answer, you want to take his result and filter out those ids that aren't found in `o1` and `o2`.

```
let o1 = _.keyBy(_.values(list1), 'id'));
let o2 = _.keyBy(list2, 'id');

let idsToPull = _.difference( _.map(o1, 'id'), _.map(o2, 'id')) //["108"]
let merged = _.values(_.merge(o1, o2 ));

let result = _.filter(merged, function(obj){ return _.indexOf(idsToPull, obj.id) === -1 })
```